# Docusign Polling Limits for templates

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on integrating **DocuSign** into our service, and one of the things I want to do is GET the details of a Template. I noticed in the documentation that Envelope endpoints are limited to one GET per endpoint per fifteen minutes.

Use case - User wants to know about template details just before sending out an envelope.

That is if an user wants to use the same template to send out 3 envelopes in a 15 min period, he will be using the get Template detail  api 3 times. Its highly unikely though

I wanted to know that whether the same rule is applicable to templates as well.
Docusign sdk ref - [get Template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templates/get/?explorer=true)

Follow up questions -

Will poling rules be violated ?
Will flags be raised ?
Can our integration key get blocked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially the [polling rules](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/api-guidelines/) you're referring to are for the [go-live process](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/).
That means they're only enforced/validated when you are attempting to take a new application from the development environment to production.

The flow you describe sounds legitimate to me, and using [Connect Webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/), which is usually the antidote for polling won't help in that case. Your need to get the template information is user initiated - so you're good.

If you [run into issues when going live](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/troubleshooting/) with your integration - you can contact support and they should be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you, we were able to pass the review